# Create script for auto startup of network station

Tags: networking, windows-explorer, script, shared-folders, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to create a script that automatically starts up a shared network station on all client computers during log in (it will appear as a hard disk drive with a drive letter in File Explorer).

From what I've read it seems like the script must be a .bat file in SYSVOL on the DC. The shared network station is located on another server in the same domain.

I have not been successful in finding out how to write the script, do anyone have any resources that can point me in the right direction?

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're on the right track... the batch file will use [`NET USE`](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) commands to map the network drive. You need to put point the AD accounts to the login script via AD login script location of with Group Policy settings which has various ways to map drives as well but a login script here in on way as well.  I typically use `NET USE P: /DELETE` and then `NET USE P: \\server\share` to map the login with the AD logon script batch file sitting in the DC sysvol method.... so those NET USE commands are what is in the batch script using the "P" or whatever drive letters.

Comment: Have a look here too: https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008... This is a simple task and you should be able to easily test this out... could show you quickly with a team viewer session. This is easy as pie as long at the user have SHARE and NTFS permissions to the `\\server\share` UNC path(s) for the drive mapped shares.

Comment: Look here for what an example script will look like as in the "example" I explained... you'd plug in the parts for your needs accordingly... i.e more drive mappings, different drive letters, and different UNC paths... https://i.imgur.com/7UhrZCh.png